# TypeError with Vuejs Emailjs Vee-validate : Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have a problem when I want to validate and transmit my data with emailjs and vee-validate.
When I don't use vee-validate it works.
Can you help me ?
Thank you

**Versions**

- vee-validate: 3.4.5
- vue: 2.6.6
- emailjs: "^3.4.0"
- emailjs-com:"^2.6.4"

ValidationProvider

```
<ValidationObserver v-slot="{handleSubmit}">
            <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(sendEmail)">
                <ValidationProvider
                    name="nom"
                    rules="required|alpha_spaces"
                    v-slot="{ errors }"
                >
                    <base-input
                        type="text"
                        v-model="name"
                        name="name"
                        class="mt-5"
                        alternative
                        placeholder="Votre nom"
                        addon-left-icon="ni ni-user-run"
                    >
                    </base-input>
                    <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                </ValidationProvider>
```

.....

```
               <base-button
                    @click="handleSubmit(sendEmail)"
                    type="pink"
                    round
                    block
                    size="lg"
                >
                    Envoyer le message
                </base-button>
            </form>
        </ValidationObserver>
```

Script :

```
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com'
export default {
  name: 'ContactUs',

  data: () => ({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: '',
  }),

  methods: {
    sendEmail(e) {
      try {
        emailjs.sendForm(
          'service_xxx',
          'template_xxx',
          e.target,
          'user_xxx',
          {
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            message: this.message,
          }
        )
      } catch (error) {
        console.log({ error })
      }

      alert('Le formulaire a été transmis !')
      // Reset form field
      this.name = ''
      this.email = ''
      this.message = ''
    },
  },
}
```

Error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined at VueComponent.sendEmail
```

Thx a lot for your help !

Comment: I'm not familiar with vee-validate or vue.js in particular, but I think that error message is fairly clear. It is saying that it is trying to access a property called 'target' on an undefined object somewhere in the VueComponent.sendEmail function. In this case it seems that the parameter "e" that is being passed into the "sendEmail" function is undefined, so make sure that when you call "sendEmail" you are passing in a valid object

Answer (score 0):

`handleSubmit` does not pass the event argument to the given callback, so `e` is undefined.

Instead of `e.target` (which would be the form element if the event were passed), you could reference the form directly with a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref):

```html
<form ref="myForm">
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    sendEmail() {
      try {
        emailjs.sendForm(
          'service_xxx',
          'template_xxx',
          this.$refs.myForm, 
          'user_xxx',
          {
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            message: this.message,
          }
        )
      } catch (error) {
        console.log({ error })
      }
    }
  }
}
```